# Check if a key is in a map then returns values with terraform

Tags: terraform

I'd like to:

1. check to see if a key exists in a map first
2. if it does then I'd like to return the key's value
3. if it doesn't, I'd like to return an empty map.

```
  replication_configuration = (contains(keys(local.s3_bucket), "${local.bucket_prefix}-${var.buckets[count.index]}")
                               ? lookup(local.s3_bucket["${local.bucket_prefix}-${var.buckets[count.index]}"], "replication_configuration", {})
                               : {})
```

however, I get this error

```
  44:   replication_configuration = (contains(keys(local.s3_bucket), "${local.bucket_prefix}-${var.buckets[count.index]}")
  45:                                ? lookup(local.s3_bucket["${local.bucket_prefix}-${var.buckets[count.index]}"], "replication_configuration", {})
  46:                                : {})
    |----------------
    | count.index is 7
    | local.bucket_prefix is "web-production"
    | local.s3_bucket is object with 1 attribute "web-production-data"
    | var.buckets is list of string with 17 elements

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are object and object, respectively.
```

I believe the error is because the "if true" part of the condition returns a map with different types.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: What is `local.s3_bucket`?